# access value returned value of child window in parent window's function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popupwindow

I am opening a popup window to make oAuth now i want to catch the final output of the child window to the function from where its been populated.

```
    $scope.login__linkedin=function() {

            var child_window=$window.open('http://localhost/oAuthTest/lrvl/public/login','Authentication', 'width=500,height=500');

            child_window.onload = function() {
                setTimeout(function(){ console.log(child_window.document.documentElement.outerHTML) }, 2000);
//i want my child window value somewhere here.
             }  

            };
```

i am not getting my final success response code (i am getting nothing actually) in console.
 I want to make login via linkedin and success in opening the window and getting the user authenticated,but the success response if showing me on my child window i want to get this response on my parent window.

Comment: Can you post more code?
Also you're overriding the onload so the first one gets never called.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `$window` with `window`

What the following gives?

```
(function() {
    var child_window=window.open('http://localhost/oAuthTest/lrvl/public/login','Authentication', 'width=500,height=500');
    child_window.onload = function() {
                setTimeout(function(){ alert(child_window.document.documentElement.outerHTML); }, 2000);
    }
})();
```

Comment: here how i tried     $scope.login__linkedin=function() {

  var child_window=window.open('http://localhost/oAuthTest/lrvl/public/login','Authentication', 'width=500,height=500');

  child_window.onload = function() {
         setTimeout(function(){ console.log(child_window.document.documentElement.outerHTML) }, 2000);
      }  
       
  };

Comment: After calling $scope.login__linkedin() is child window open? Is there any error or warning in the console?

Comment: You cannot take your child window value in the place you've commented. Because the value will be taken only after 2 seconds but you want to use it right now.

Comment: Can you execute in your console
    (function() {
        var child_window=window.open('http://localhost/oAuthTest/lrvl/public/login','Authentication', 'width=500,height=500');
        child_window.onload = function() {
            setTimeout(function(){ alert(child_window.document.documentElement.outerHTML); }, 2000);
        }
    })();

Comment: I am using angularjs then is it needed to user (funciton(){})() >?

Comment: doesn't matter. Just execute it in console when your page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Open your child window

```
 var child_window=$window.open('http://localhost/oAuthTest/lrvl/public/login','Authentication', 'width=500,height=500');
```

(I'm sure this is from the same domain)

Add a function for the popup window to execute. This function can transfer some data from Popup to Caller through arguments.

```
child_window.selectUser = function(userId) {
     console.log(userId);

     //Do whatever you like with this authenticated user
}
```

Now your popup window has `selectUser` function which it can call after authenticating the user.

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: i don't have my server end code live so i believe it my code not going to work on fiddle